# How to configure Vuze to start downloading files in queue when total download speed is slow

Tags: bittorrent, vuze

I can download at about 300K/s, however sometimes I'll see in Vuze it's downloading at only 30K/s with many files in the queue. I have to force those files to start, then I'll get around 300K/s for the total download speed.

I want to setup Vuze so that if the total download speed of all files is below a certain amount, it will start up other downloads in the queue. There are many settings in Vuze, but I haven't found anything for this.

How can this be setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Options > Queue

Set the Max Simultaneous downloads to something higher, this will allow more torrents to be active and downloading at one time.

You can also Uncheck "Don't start any more torrents when upload/download speed limit is reached"